# Modal open using getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal in my website. I need to use that modal all of my pages. So I cannot use IDs in modal script. Here is my js code

```
var modal = document.getElementById('demo-modal');
var btn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
var close = modal.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
};

close.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

Then I changed above getElementById to getElementsByClassName and my html changed IDs to classes but it's not working at all.

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('demo-modal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('open-modal');
var close = modal.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95zcto1p/). 
Any ideas?

Comment: ```getElementsByClassName``` will give array of HTML elements and hence you can use,  ```document.getElementsByClassName('demo-modal')[0]``` and ```document.getElementsByClassName('open-modal')[0]``` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

`getElementsByClassName` behaves different than `getElementById`.
[getElementsByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp) : This returns a collection of an element's child elements with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('open-modal')[0];
var close = modal.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];



btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
};

close.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 0.5s
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 12px;
}

.modal-footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-modal" name="open-modal-btn">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal demo-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class='close'>X</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```